# What happens if two websites have the same name?

Tags: domains

I was wondering if there are two websites whose owners name them the same, for example, `example.com`. If I typed in the URL on my browser, which site would I go to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two websites can't have the same name because registrars only allow one owner per domain name.

If someone has already registered `example.com`, nobody else can use it until it is abandoned by its owner.

Comment: Thanks! You answered my question.

Comment: Note that there were at some point "alternate roots", which means that depending on how to you configure your local DNS resolution you would hit either the IANA root or something else. In those setup, a given name may exist separately in each root and hence resolve to things completely different. Of course this creates huge problems of naming  and breaks a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Technically it is registries that implement the "one owner per domain name", not registrars. Registrars send orders to the registry, which is one per TLD and maintains the database. In this database, a given domain name has a unique property so the registry will reject any second attempt to register a specific domain name if it exists already in its database.